# I Cannot Delete nfs4 ACE Permission

Tags: ipa, nfs

Hi in my linux file explorer. 
I have finished dealing with nfs under version 4, and added ace permissions in nfs4.
But I cannot delete aces.

permissions for an example folder is,

```
-sh-4.2$ nfs4_getfacl how
A::OWNER@:rwaDxtTcCy
A::1948800001:rwaDxtcy
A::GROUP@:rxtcy
A::EVERYONE@:rxtcy
```

I added "A::1948800001:rwaDxtcy" by the command below.

```
nfs4_setfacl -a A::1948800001:rwaDxtcy how
```

I tried to remove it by chaning option from -a to -x.

```
nfs4_setfacl -x A::1948800001:rwaDxtcy how
```

It returns nothing like when it doesn't have any error.

Please help I'm really stuck here.